# Determining where a sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $D$ denote the set of values $x$ for which the sequence $\left(\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, and define a function $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}$. Determine where $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Workings:

I know that function is convergent when $x = 0, x = 1, 0 < x < 1, -1 < x < 0, x < -1, x > 1.$

At $x = 0$:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x^n}{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} 1+x^n} = \frac{0}{1+0} = 0 = f(0)$

So $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

At $x = 1:$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} x^n}{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} 1+x^n} = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2} = f(1)$

So $f(x)$ is continuous at $1$.

I'm not sure what to do for the other x values however. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When $|x|<1$ then $x^n\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and when $|x|>1$ then $x^n \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Do you know what uniform convergence is?

Comment: @Reveillark I don't know about uniform convergence